# Proper way to extend a Ruby Class?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am trying to extend the Smtpapi::Header class in order to stay DRY. Is this the proper way to set these original Smtpapi setters in my extension? I am new to Ruby.

```
  class CustomMailerHeader < Smtpapi::Header

    def initialize(params)

        super
    end

    def no_service_header
          self.add_category("Service Down Email")
          self.add_filter('templates', 'enable', 1)
          self.add_filter('templates', 'template_id', '8bawd1-9e66') 
          self.add_substitution('-|A_MESSAGE|-', ['server down'])
          self.set_tos('admin@admin.com')
          self
    end

end
```

Then use it like this

```
header = CustomMailerHeader.new.no_service_header
```

Comment: That won't work. `new` require one argument, and you are not passing any.

Answer (score 0):

That'll work, though `CustomMailerHeader.new` would just be the same thing as `CustomMailerHeader.new` so you can abstract away the `no_service_header` and clean it up a bit:

```
def initialize
  super
  no_service_header
end

private

def no_service_header
  add_category("Service Down Email")
  add_filter('templates', 'enable', 1)
  add_filter('templates', 'template_id', '8bawd1-9e66') 
  add_substitution('-|A_MESSAGE|-', ['server down'])
  set_tos('admin@admin.com')
end
```

Usage:

```
header = CustomMailerHeader.new
```

Comment: Thank you! I assumed "super" had to be the last thing called like some other languages.